# how to place bootstrap panels over image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place bootstrap panels over a image, but I added the image, but I cannot see the panels at all , so need to know how to place panels over the picture. Here is the html code

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="auroraXbodypic">
                    <div class="auroraXpanelBody">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                      Basic panel example
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                      Basic panel example
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the CSS for the picture

```
.auroraXbodypic {
    content:url(../images/pic.png);

}
```

Basically I am trying to show two panels on the picture side by side.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cts6rgmt)**

Comment: please set up a jsfiddle, codepen or some other show case for us. Thanks :)

Comment: Sure give me  2 minutes

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cts6rgmt/

Comment: Did you actually considered use the image as a background image? If not, why?

Answer (score 0):

Change your css like:

```
.auroraXbodypic {
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /* for Chrome and Safari */
    background-size: cover; /* for others */
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cts6rgmt/2/)

Comment: hey! but the picture just is half now, doesn't show full width , I tried writing width 100% and height 100% but did not work

Comment: I updated the post to display the image in full width and height of it's container.

Comment: I wrote this code, but I am still not getting full picture, I tried this code and it works  height:100vh; 
But not sure if its the right way

Comment: if u give a height to your auroraXbodypic the image takes all the place, this is a normal behavior. https://jsfiddle.net/cts6rgmt/3/

Comment: The second way is to use <img> like that  : https://jsfiddle.net/cts6rgmt/6/ Make sure to accept the answer if it helped. Cheers